# timed loop in android service not performing as expected

Tags: android, firebase, android-service

I am creating my first service which needs to do something every 5 minutes.  The results I am getting are close to what they should be not quite.  I am trying to just log the time to my firebase every 5 minutes.

Results:

```
-K1T1GtyTfdJM_3dIvHe: "Date: 25, time:21:07"
-K1T60t8YEPghiqUpPnt: "Date: 25, time:21:27"
-K1T60tDPRg7RmdDUwjG: "Date: 25, time:21:27"
-K1T60taul-iMquEQUM6: "Date: 25, time:21:27"
-K1T60tbdyvIey9SINdm: "Date: 25, time:21:27"
-K1TBM_qDLQLnaeNB4x-: "Date: 25, time:21:50"
-K1TBM_sWiIkI0e1usqS: "Date: 25, time:21:50"
-K1TBM_sWiIkI0e1usqT: "Date: 25, time:21:50"
-K1TBM_tH8S4cTPUQ-NV: "Date: 25, time:21:50"
-K1TBcxo0UYS4h-uw1pA: "Date: 25, time:21:52"
-K1TGXIDMPPlyM5byhy9: "Date: 25, time:22:13"
-K1TGXOS7j8U_yeBh5zl: "Date: 25, time:22:13"
-K1TGXOS7j8U_yeBh5zm: "Date: 25, time:22:13"
-K1TGXOTvKvrmCSpCjWw: "Date: 25, time:22:13"
```

Service:

```
public class locationCheckService extends IntentService {

public locationCheckService() {
    super("locationCheckService");
}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("Service running");
    final Firebase testRef = new Firebase("https://myurl.firebaseio.com/androidTest");


    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hours = now.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            int minutes = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            int ampm = now.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
            int hours24 = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int date = now.get(Calendar.DATE);
            String fireTime = "Date: " + date + ", time:" + String.format("%02d:%02d", hours24, minutes);
            String time = String.format("%02d:%02d", hours, minutes);
            if(ampm == 0){
                Log.i("tag", time + " am");

            } else {
                Log.i("tag", time + " pm");
            }
            Log.i("fire", fireTime);
            testRef.push().setValue(fireTime);
        }
    },0,300000);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
}
}
```

As you can see, it does get fired the correct amount of times, but it seems to miss it 3-4 times and then try and catch up.  Can someone explain to me why this happens and/or if there is a way to fix this?

Also, it did act correctly when the device was connected to the PC for debugging and the app was open.

Comment: So the app is closed when you run this test and get these failed results?

Comment: It is in the background, yes.

Comment: Well then, that could be an explainable cause for the  results you get. Doublecheck your service background running policy. It takes time to spawn a new process, it takes resources to execute - and your thread/process may be of lower priority compared other running apps/services.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to do that?  Or link me to something that does.

Comment: IntentService is designed to digest an incoming intent and stop immediately after. This means your thread gets killed after it's started. You need to write a separate service that can run continuously, and then from this intent service simply pass the data to the permanent service to process it as you desire.

Comment: Ive added my suggestion as an answer.

Comment: What is the real use case here? This is almost certainly an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) and heartbeats are generally a hack. A better answer is probably to use [onDisconnect()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/offline-capabilities.html), but it's hard to know without a real use case.

Comment: Constant location tracking which requires accurate results and good battery life.  Can't set the interval of the location request to 5 mins because it will just return the first result.  I need to keep requesting locations until X accuracy is met and then wait 5 mins again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a power-conserving feature, your device will go to sleep if no apps are requesting that it stays up (usually through a WakeLock). This means that all CPUs are paused, and no processes get to run. When the device wakes up for some reason, your process gets the chance to catch up a little.

The device never goes to sleep when it's charging, which is why you didn't see the problem while connected to your computer.

You should be able to get your code running reliably using [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) or [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Note that waking up a device every 5 minutes may have negative impact on battery life.

Comment: Although it may work, -1'd because the solution has negative impact on battery life.

Comment: Since battery life wasn't part of the use case or a stated optimization requirement, this doesn't seem like a non-useful answer; inversely, it seems quite useful, so a comment on battery life may be helpful, but a downvote seems detrimental.

Comment: Makes sense. Will revert when permitted.

Comment: The thing is, there is no solution that will *not* impact battery life. If you want to do something every 5 minutes, you're going to have to wake up the phone every 5 minutes. And that costs power.

Comment: Truth be told, there are other much greater power savy concerns than a job scheduler ;) Waking up an app from time to time could be an expensive operation, as it loads resources etc. But running an independent lightweight service could save some power. But doing that would imply some extra work that it's rarely available.

Comment: Yeah, but that "lightweight service" of yours will still be subject to the device going to sleep -- so it won't do the update at the desired time. It doesn't matter how many active Services you have, you can't run when the CPU is asleep.